# Meaning of up to

Tags: meaning

I would like to interpret this sentence:
"Try to perform this for 1–2 minutes, rest for 30–60 seconds, and repeat up to 5 times"

Do I have to repeat it five times or can I repeat it 1,2,3,4,5 times? So it's up to me, but not more than five times?

Answer (score 2):

"Up to 5 times" in this context means, as you suggested, to repeat any number of times leading up to five. If the direction was to repeat [the activity] exactly 5 times, the correct way to express this would be "Repeat 5 times."

"Repeat up to 5 times" could also be expressed as: "Repeat 1-5 times", as earlier in the context, when the direction was given: "Perform this for 1-2 minutes."

Comment: Of course, "It's up to your wife" carries an entirely different connotation.