# Does "freed doctors to perform abortions for any reason in the first trimester" mean that the law "allowed abortion up to the second trimester"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

For the past few years, I have had a long and arduous argument with my English teacher about an exam question she gave us, and I am curious what you all think about it. For context, I attend an Austrian school, so we do not speak English as our native language.

The question at issue is Q2 concerning regulations on abortion after 1973. We came to the conclusion that both her and my answers are correct, so the real question is which answer is more precise. I believe option A to be more accurate as all regulations after 1973 would necessarily allow abortion in the first trimester, while she believes option B to be correct because those regulations would still allow abortion in some cases.

**The relevant text passage states**: "Finally, abortion was once again legalised in 1973 in all fifty states, using a trimester framework that freed doctors to perform abortions
for any reason in the first trimester and giving the individual states the power to regulate the second and third trimester."

**Q2 states the following**:

Regulations on abortion after 1973

- **A** allowed abortion up to the second trimester.
- **B** allowed abortion throughout the US.
- **C** banned abortion after the second trimester.
- **D** banned abortion in individual states.

I am curious to hear what you all think. Thank you!

Comment: So the question is actually about what "up to the second trimester" means: whether that includes those months or excludes them.

Comment: “. . . once again legalized in 1973 in all fifty states” is an incorrect premise.  Why debate such inaccuracies? Many other questions deal with “up to” issues, so this is a duplicate.

Comment: [This question is about "up to five times"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/530426/meaning-of-up-to) which obviously means five or less. "Up to" is generally inclusive, but no more. Even with "Up to 100 days" it's ambiguous at what point on the final day, so it's not entirely clear-cut.

Comment: Regardless, I advise you to get over it. Language is inevitably ambiguous and holding a grudge over an exam question is not going to help you, it will just make you a sadder and less successful person. We get a lot of similar questions, but you need to treat it as a learning experience on how to deal with life's ambiguities, not be desperately trying to litigate it for the rest of your life.

Comment: Syntactically, (b) is correct: *Abortion was once again legalised in 1973 in all fifty states*. The rest is parenthetical content that qualifies the statement.

Answer (score 1):

The issue with your answer is that "up to" is often interpreted as "only up to". A law that permits abortions "up to 6 weeks", for example, would be widely interpreted as prohibiting abortions after 6 weeks.

You could see the answer getting a little absurd, but no less true, if you changed it to "allowed abortions up to 1 day". The law did allow that, but it's not a very good summary of the law, and can be outright misleading in certain contexts. Neither answer is wrong, but I can see why B might be preferred.